# convert double value 123.0 to 123.00

Tags: java, division

I need to display two decimal value. on doing `Double d=(Double) 123400/100`; I am getting result as `d=1234.0`; I used DecimalFormat and it gives result as `d=1234`. I need the result as `d=1234.00`.

```
Double d = (Double) 123400d / 100;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print("Formatted : " + df.format(d));
```

Comment: Maybe post the code you have written up until now?

Comment: `DecimalFormat` has a [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), so I suggest you to read it first.

Comment: Double d=(Double)1234/100; System.out.print("D = "+d);

Comment: (1) Use [edit] option under your post to add informations like code you used in your question, (2) you said "* I used DecimalFormat and it gives result as d=1234*", I don't see any DecimalFormat in your example.

Comment: Double d=(Double)123400/100 will not compile

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
double d= 123400/100.;
String s = String.format("%.2f", d);
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Double d=(Double) 123400/100;
```

This statement must cause a compile time error stating that int cannot be cast to double.

Now solution for your problem is text formating. go with java.text.DecimalFormat;.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class FormatClazz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d = 123400/100 * 1.00;
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        System.out.println((df2.format(d)));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the min fraction digits like this

```
setMinimumFractionDigits(2)
```

E.g.

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d = (Double) 123400.0 / 100;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        System.out.print("Formatted : " + df.format(d));
    }
}
```

Output

```
Formatted : 1234.00
```